# pandas read_csv: pull multiple series out of a single column

Tags: csv, pandas

I have csv data like this:

```
requests_per_sec, 9:00, 100
requests_per_sec, 9:01, 101
...
response_time, 9:00, 40ms
repsonse_time, 9:01, 42ms
...
error_rate, 9:00, 0.01
...
```

so I have this:

```
pd.read_csv(csv_data,index_col=[1], names= ['metric', 'time', 'value'], parse_dates=True)
```

which gives me a dataframe indexed by time, with the columns: metric and value. But I'd need to split that dataframe so that I don't have 3 data sets in the same column but rather 3 independent series (requests_per_sec, response_time and error_rate). Is there a way to do that directly from read_csv? Or do I need some .groupby() or .select() manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just in two seperate steps: first read the data and then reshape it.
E.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

s = """metric,timestamp,datapoint
A,2013-01-01,1
A,2013-01-02,5
A,2013-01-03,8
B,2013-01-01,2
B,2013-01-02,3
B,2013-01-03,4
C,2013-01-01,8
C,2013-01-02,7
C,2013-01-03,6"""
```

First you just read the data:

```
In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), parse_dates=[1])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  metric           timestamp  datapoint
0      A 2013-01-01 00:00:00          1
1      A 2013-01-02 00:00:00          5
2      A 2013-01-03 00:00:00          8
3      B 2013-01-01 00:00:00          2
4      B 2013-01-02 00:00:00          3
5      B 2013-01-03 00:00:00          4
6      C 2013-01-01 00:00:00          8
7      C 2013-01-02 00:00:00          7
8      C 2013-01-03 00:00:00          6
```

And then you can transform it, in this case reshape it with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) to create columns for the different metrics:

```
In [7]: df.pivot(index='timestamp', columns='metric', values='datapoint')
Out[7]:
metric      A  B  C
timestamp
2013-01-01  1  2  8
2013-01-02  5  3  7
2013-01-03  8  4  6
```

Comment: this appears to be exactly what I wanted. Thank you joris!